# Random Effects ANOVA with test for difference in variances

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, variance, random-effects-model

Say I have a study measuring a continuous endpoint for 3 sample assays on two days, i.e. before and after intervention. The measurements are performed several times by different people (repeated measurements), of which one person is considered as the "gold standard". The samples before and after intervention are different.
My question now is whether the variance in measurements could be reduced by the intervention (a training)?

To analyse this study, I can create a model for the individual days with "person" as a random effect. But how to test the difference in variances? Hardly the solution is to write out the variances and compare them manually in an F-test. However, before/after is not a fixed effect in the model and still I have the repeated measurements. How can I conclude an answer to the above question?

Note: Due to my job I had to switch to SAS. Nevertheless, I am also happy about R-based answers. Keywords and references desired.

fake data could be:

```
> fakedat
   day assay person EP1 Ref
1    0     1      1  85  85
2    0     1      1  75  85
3    0     1      1  30  85
4    0     1      2  85  85
5    0     1      2  75  85
6    0     1      2  30  85
7    0     1      3  85  85
8    0     1      3  75  85
9    0     1      3  30  85
10   0     2      1  85  85
11   0     2      1  75  85
12   0     2      1  30  85
13   0     2      2  85  85
14   0     2      2  75  85
15   0     2      2  30  85
16   0     2      3  85  85
17   0     2      3  75  85
18   0     2      3  30  85
19   0     3      1  85  85
20   0     3      1  75  85
21   0     3      1  30  85
22   0     3      2  85  85
23   0     3      2  75  85
24   0     3      2  30  85
25   0     3      3  85  85
26   0     3      3  75  85
27   0     3      3  30  85
28   1     1      1  85  85
29   1     1      1  75  85
30   1     1      1  30  85
31   1     1      2  85  85
32   1     1      2  75  85
33   1     1      2  30  85
34   1     1      3  85  85
35   1     1      3  75  85
36   1     1      3  30  85
37   1     2      1  85  85
38   1     2      1  75  85
39   1     2      1  30  85
40   1     2      2  85  85
41   1     2      2  75  85
42   1     2      2  30  85
43   1     2      3  85  85
44   1     2      3  75  85
45   1     2      3  30  85
46   1     3      1  85  85
47   1     3      1  75  85
48   1     3      1  30  85
49   1     3      2  85  85
50   1     3      2  75  85
51   1     3      2  30  85
52   1     3      3  85  85
53   1     3      3  75  85
54   1     3      3  30  85
```

(let me know how to attach the csv)

Comment: Differences in variances of *what*? You have a random effect for person effects, as well as a residual variance. Which variance? Are you doing a 1 tail test for variance exceeding a threshold, or are you testing for presence/absence of person level effect?

Comment: I am not interested in person level effects. The final null hypothesis would be that the variances (before and after) are equal, which I would like to reject. Still, I am struggeling with the right model form beforehand.

Comment: I am wondering if I can include "day" (if seen as intervention 0/1) as a fixed effect? Second thought was to simply calculate coefficient of variation for each person on an assay before and after and see if there is a difference in a usual t-test? Also I get confused with the term "intra-class correlation coefficient in a mixed model", if this is what I am looking for. I am just not sure about approaching this problem. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I think you are confusing a couple concepts here. Let's forget about random effects. Suppose you have a simple pre/post design for some intervention. The obvious question is: does the intervention work? As a hypothesis, you want to know whether the coefficient for the pre/post indicator is different from 0. It just so happens to be the case that that hypothesis is equivalent to asking whether the variance is lower *after adjustment for the pre/post indicator*. I think you're confusing this with asking whether the variance is lower in the post period than in the pre period.